# Combine bar plot and line plot with secondary Y axis in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I want to plot a graph in R with ggplot() function like this,
[image]

I have this code:

```
ggplot(inc, aes(age, num, fill = sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge",color="black",width = 0.6) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=num-se, ymax=num+se), width=.3,
                   position=position_dodge(.6)) +
  theme_classic()+
  theme(legend.position="top",
        legend.justification="left")+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Pastel1", limits = c("Female", "Male"))+
  labs(x = "Age (years)", y="Incident cases")+
  geom_ribbon(data=inc,aes(ymin =lowerrate, ymax = upperrate), alpha =0.3)+
  geom_line(data=inc,aes(age,rate, group = sex ))
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~(./atrisk)*100000, name = "secondary axis"))
```

but the result is the picture below:

[image]

Can someone explain why the line plot and secondary Y axis are not shown in the plot?
(In the sec_axis() I use the variable **atrisk** and the error is for not monotonic transformation.)
How can I fix the Issue?

Comment: You are missing + before the last line code

Comment: Thank you . Yes, I had a mistake. But after adding + before last line code, I was faced with this error. (Error in f(...) : object 'atrisk' not found) because I used a variable "atrisk" in sec_axis(). Can we add a second Y axis without monotonic transformation of the first axis?

Comment: Can you provide dataset, as it is hard to replicate without data. You can also just give a few rows.

Comment: Yes sure! my data is in this format: inc=data.frame( age=c("15 to 19","15 to 19","20 to 24","20 to 24",..., ">=95",">=95"),sex=c("M","F","M","F",...,"M","F"), num=c(138.43, 97.51,...), rate=c(0.04,0.03,0.09,...), atrisk=c(317782109.1,301758869, ...))

Comment: In sec_axis() the variable of the second Y axis must be a monotonic transformation of the variable of the first Y axis (num). Here the variable of the second axis has a function of num as you see in the last line code. (num/atrisk)*100000.